# .NET XmlSerializer bug when two classes have properties with the same name

Tags: .net, xmlserializer

Have your flaming torches ready people! Someone on the Internet is suggesting there is a bug in the .NET framework! :-)

Consider this contrived model:

```
public class Barn
{
    public Horse Horse { get; set; }
    public Motorcycle Motorcycle { get; set; }
}

public class Horse
{
    public Horse()
    {
        Rider = "Jim Craig";
    }

    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true, Namespace = "abc")]
    public string Rider { get; set; }
}

public class Motorcycle
{
    public Motorcycle()
    {
        Rider = "Ghost";
    }

    [XmlElement(IsNullable = false, Namespace = "abc")]
    public string Rider { get; set; }
}
```

Note the two `Rider` properties that share the same name and namespace, but are otherwise unrelated. One is XML nullable, the other is not.

Here is some code to XML serialize and then deserialize a null horse rider:

```
// Create a Barn, with a Horse, with a null Rider
Barn barnBefore = new Barn();
barnBefore.Horse = new Horse();
barnBefore.Horse.Rider = null;

// Serialize and then deserialize the Barn
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Barn));
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
serializer.Serialize(stream, barnBefore);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Barn barnAfter = (Barn)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

// Is the Horse's Rider still null?
Console.WriteLine(barnAfter.Horse.Rider == null ? "null" : "not null");
```

The `Horse`'s `Rider` property has `IsNullable = true`, so its null value should be maintained through the serialization. Running the above code, the output is indeed **null**. So far so good.

Now, here's the fun part: swap the order of the `Horse` and `Motorcycle` properties in the `Barn` class, so that `Motorcycle` comes first.

Run it again, and now the output is **not null**. What the hell?!

I've tested on VS 2008 and 2010.

For more fun, try making the two `Rider` properties different types, for example one a `string` and the other an `int`. That *really* screw ups up `XmlSerializer`.

I'm not interested in how to work around this issue. That's trivial. My question is: is this a bug, or what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I'd be curious to see what the serialized XML looks like -- with the properties in the original order and after you swap them. Maybe it's an issue with the *serialization* and not the *deserialization.*

Comment: @Cory Original: `<Horse><Rider xsi:nil="true" xmlns="abc" /></Horse>` Swapped: `<Horse />` It is serializing it as though `IsNullable` were false.

Comment: Very interesting - and digging into the XML Serialisation to try and figure this out was also very elightening - +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in the first case the written XML looks a bit like this:

```
<Barn>
  <Horse>
    <Rider xsi:nil="true" xmlns="abc" />
  </Horse>
</Barn>
```

However in the second case the XML looks like this:

```
<Barn>
  <Horse />
</Barn>
```

So in the second case essentially what is happening during deserialisation is this:

```
Barn barn = new Barn();
barn.Hose = new Horse();
```

And so because we are setting the Rider by default in the constructor it is left as "Jim Craig".

What is interesting is that the behaviour can be reversed simply by changing the order of the elements in `Barn`.  To try and discover more we can do some digging around using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) and [Sgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - simply run `sgen` against our assembly and take a peek at the generated assembly.

What we find is that in the first case the generated code in **both** the `Write2_Horse` and `Write3_Motorcycle` methods has a line that looks like this:

```
base.WriteNullableStringLiteral("Rider", "abc", o.Rider);
```

However in the second case it looks like this:

```
base.WriteElementString("Rider", "abc", o.Rider);
```

I can't see any reason why changing the order of the elements like this should change the serialisation behaviour of both the `Horse` and `Motorcycle` elements in this this way, so in short this looks like to me like a bug in the XML serialisation assembly generator.

You should probably report it to Microsoft :-)

Comment: Cool analysis of the generated IL. I have submitted the bug report at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/661274